# Seq.cache with Seq.unfold in F#

Tags: f#, seq, unfold

I'm trying to cache the result of an infinite sequence of triangle numbers.

```
let triCalc n = (n*(n+1))/2
let triNumC = 0 |> Seq.unfold (fun n -> Some((triCalc n, n+1))) |> Seq.cache
```

However, when I try to cache it doesn't seem to work as I expect

```
let x = Seq.take 4 (triNumC)
let y = Seq.take 4 (triNumC)

printf "%A" x
printf "%A" y
```

This prints

```
seq [0; 1; 3; 6]seq [0; 1; 3; 6]
```

Am I caching incorrectly? Shouldn't the second sequence printed be a continuation of the first? I am not quite sure how to progress.

Comment: If that were the case, `Seq.take` would have to mutate `triNumC`, which sounds like a bad idea. `cache` isolates subsequent enumerations from the source.

Comment: @Asti Okay, I think that makes sense. So disregarding the multiple Seq.take, is the cache done correctly?

Comment: Yes, the first printf  would cause the `unfold` to evaluate, but the second printf wouldn't.

Comment: by default the expressions are pure...both x and y are equivalent to the same expression, so you would (normally) expect them to be equivalient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the continuation you need to skip.   The sequence remains the same

```
let y = triNumC
        |> Seq.skip 4
        |> Seq.take 4
```

Caching is fine. The benefit of caching is that when calculating *y* is that starts from the 5th term onwards since the first 4 are already cached.